# How to run query in mapbasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I made a Query in Mapbasic like :

```
Dim query As String
query = "Select * from some_table"
```

How to run **query** to form table? Is it possible to save selected value in variable without forming table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just run the SQL command right in the MapBasic code:

```
Select * from some_table into mySelection
```

If you do need to store the SQL query in a string (dynmic SQL string etc) you can execute it using [RunCommand](http://www.kxcad.net/MapInfo/MapInfo_Professional/MapInfow-32-68.html)

```
Dim query As String
query = "Select * from some_table into mySelection"
Run Command query
```

In order to get the values from the table you need to use Fetch

```
Dim value as String
Fetch First From mySelection
value = mySelection.{ColumnName}
```

You will have to write a loop using Fetch First and Fetch Next to loop over all the records to do something with each one.